# Mutably iterate over all permutations of Vec

Tags: rust, rust-itertools

I need to mutably iterate over the `Vec` `model.circles`, so I get all permutations of two elements.

However, I can't get it to compile:

```rust
for ij in (0..model.circles.len()).permutations(2) {
    let i = ij[0];
    let j = ij[1];
    let circle = &mut model.circles[i];
    let other = &mut model.circles[j]; // cannot borrow `model.circles` as mutable more than once at a time

    // Mutating both elements
}
```

I get this error:

```
cannot borrow `model.circles` as mutable more than once at a time
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: @mousetail I can't split the Vec because the 2 elements are not near each other

Comment: There are a lot of other answers under that question, some of which would apply to your situation

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't split **anywhere** in between the 2 elements in question. At least not if they're in fact distinct.

Comment: Permutations should always be distinct

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14cd4fb05e2a49ccdb832ed1fdb0ffb6)